# Userfrosting ExtendedMailMessage not clearing attachments

Tags: php, userfrosting

I am using the ExtendedMailMessage class to try and send an email with an attachments to my clients. The issue is I am sending the email inside a foreach loop and for some reason even though I am defining a new attachment the new attachment is just being appended to an array and each client gets multiple attachments instead of one.

```
$extendedMailer = $this->ci->extendedMailer;

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $attachment = new MailAttachment(
        base64_decode($base64String), "report.pdf"
    );

    try {
        $message = new ExtendedTwigMailMessage($this->ci->view, 'mail/pdf-reports.html.twig');

        $message->from($config['address_book.admin'])
            ->addEmailRecipient(new EmailRecipient($email, 'Client'))
            ->setFromEmail($config['address_book.admin'])
            ->setReplyEmail($config['address_book.admin'])
            ->addAttachment($attachment);

        $extendedMailer->sendDistinct($message);
    }
    catch(\Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($email);
    }
}
```

The first client will receive 1 attachment and then the 2nd will receive 2 attachments, 3rd will receive 3 attachments etc...

How do I just send 1 attachement with each email instead of appending it to the old attachments

Comment: Since `addAttachment` is not part of UserFrosting code, it would be necessary to see you implemented it in `ExtendedTwigMailMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `PHPMailer` instance is reused for each email, anything set on PHPMailer is carried on to the next email. When the Mailer's `send` or `sendDistinct` methods are called, [only the recipients are explicitly cleared](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/cc80d4113ba8788b1c1279702b31c82b6a95398a/app/sprinkles/core/src/Mail/Mailer.php#L206). So in your case, you might need to explicitly clear the attachement from `$message` between each email (depending how your `addAttachment` is implemented).

Another solution might be to move the `addAttachment` call outside the loop, assuming each email as the same attachement :

```php
$extendedMailer = $this->ci->extendedMailer;

$attachment = new MailAttachment(
    base64_decode($base64String), "report.pdf"
);

$message = new ExtendedTwigMailMessage($this->ci->view, 'mail/pdf-reports.html.twig');
$message->from($config['address_book.admin'])
        ->setFromEmail($config['address_book.admin'])
        ->setReplyEmail($config['address_book.admin'])
        ->addAttachment($attachment);

foreach ($emails as $email) {
   
    try {
        $message->addEmailRecipient(new EmailRecipient($email, 'Client'));
        $extendedMailer->sendDistinct($message);
    }
    catch(\Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($email);
    }
}
```

Note that [the following fix](https://github.com/userfrosting/sprinkle-core/blob/cd31acb270851dd8d16b4ff8a1ab1ef8924cb1de/app/src/Mail/Mailer.php#L142-L143) will be introduced in UserFrosting V5 `send/sendDistinct` to avoid this issue :

```php
// Clone phpMailer so we don't have to reset it after sending.
$phpMailer = clone $this->phpMailer;
```